# Bootstrap 3.3.7 dropdown list doesn't display inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I would like to display the dropdown elements inline on mobile devices,preferably on the entire width of the screen However, I tried fixing it in CSS but cannot seem to make it work.

As for the CSS, I tried giving the *li* tags a `display: inline` property but it had no effect.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-5">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navCollapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navCollapse">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills list-inline">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Gallery<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu list-inline">
                    <li><a href="#">Mercury-Earth</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mars-Saturn</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Uranus-Pluto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post the css you've added trying to make it work

Comment: try using .row class?

Comment: try col-sm-5 instead of col-sm-3, that would work